# Free variables in echelon form.

Tags: linear-algebra

If free variables are the variables that aren't basic variables, then how did this example come up with x4?

Reduced echelon form:

```
-1 0 2 0 
0 -1 3 0 
0  0 0 0  
0  0 0 0  


x1 = 2x3
x2 = 3x3
x3 and x4 are free
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic variables corresponding to columns containing an entry that is the first nonzero entry in a row: in this case $x_1$ and $x_2$.  Anything else is free.  That includes cases where the column has no nonzero entries at all, which is what you have with $x_4$ in your example.